# Marked as duplicate even if I explained that it was not a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I posted [this question here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/164758/are-metasploit-built-in-exploits-used-in-real-life-pen-testing) and of course got the eternal couple of comments suggesting that it was a duplicate. I clarified things saying that I asked a totally different question (namely, are the built-in exploits **inside** Metasploit used in real-life pentesting, and **not** if Metasploit itself was used in real-life pentesting). However, a few hours after my clarification the question got marked as exact duplicate and closed.

So is this really stackexchange policy in all of its websites? I'm not new here, I've been using SO for a few years and answering questions for a couple of years aswell, but I'm really starting to get tired of the eagerness of the people here to close questions.

Can someone here please explain me how my question can be an **exact** duplicate of a question that didn't by any mean ask the for same thing?

Comment: So, your question is how often the community-supplied exploits are used or how often a 'real' pentester writes their own exploit using the metasploit framework to deliver the exploit? I'm not sure that's answerable.

Comment: I don't think I said "how often" somewhere. I just wanted some answers from experienced pentesters saying : "Yes, I do use them most of time" or "I sometimes use them and sometimes write my own" or "I never use them, I always write my own" or "I never use them nor anyone of my fellow pentesters". I didn't ask for any explicit exploit name, so I highly doubt there is much of secret in answering. I just asked for some kind of real-world best-practices.

Comment: "how often" being a function of how many use it that way .... As I have said, one uses the tool that is efficient for the task. One engagement might be possible with Metasploit out of the box, another engagement might require something completely different. You appear to be wanting to collect experiences, which would still make the question off-topic as not a Q&A style question.

Answer (score 1):

A question can be a duplicate even though it may seem different at first, if it effectively answers the question in another way or provides answers that are equivalent.

In looking at this one, it very much looks like a duplicate to me.